# Unable to launch Yodlee FastLink 2.0 (Integration guide for the web)

Tags: html, forms, yodlee

I'm following this link: https://developer.yodlee.com/Fastlink_2.0/FastLink_Integration_Guide_for_Web for launching Yodlee's Fastlink 2.0

I have obtained the RSessionTokens and authenticator token.

My HTML form post looks like this:

Processing...

FinappId : 
RSession : 
Redirect : 
Token : 
Extra Params :

But when I click on submit, it gives me an error page saying - "Technical Difficulties with error code".

When I try opening https://node.developer.yodlee.com/, it takes me to a page which says - "No FinApp specified."

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if you have passed FinAppId. (10003600-Aggregation; 10003620 - Instant account verification)

Then check the parameters which you are passing are following the URL:
https://node.developer.yodlee.com/authenticate/restserver/

For Ex:
https://node.developer.yodlee.com/**finapp**/10003600/?brand=10010352&**id**=10003600&appId=3A4CAE9B711Q1CCD7FF41F51006E9ED00&channelId=-1&version=9.55&status=published&c=csit_key_0:gyKnWdaQx1HszC570IFd2Jwvayk=&finappCDNURL=&**resturl**=https%3A%2F%2F111.12.25.88%2Fservices%2Fsrest%2Frestserver&l=

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Krithik